# How to know update size on the osX?

Tags: macos, updates

I pay for cellular internet and use a phone as a hotspot for a mac. I should always know how big the update for OS X is, however I cannot find any way to know the size before I start the download. The last update was 500 000 mB and I stopped the downloading immediately. I suppose that partial downloads are not healthy for the disk drive and OS, but the main issue is financial one.

The apple does not provide the size of update.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -l` will display the size of the update in its listing of available updates. Take a peek at the man page for `softwareupdate` to learn about its features.

Comment: worked for me. great help!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to go to [Apple's download part of the website](http://support.apple.com/downloads/) before you download the update, search for the update you want, and then scroll down. Just below the SHA1 code, and above the System Requirements, you will see the download size

A screenshot:

[image]

This may be a bit annoying, but at least it won't use all of your mobile data allowance.

If you're in Mavericks, then app updates can be shown by clicking the updates tab in app store, click the apps name, and on the right it shows you.

Note: the link takes you to featured downloads. Just click the "Browse By Product" button to see all for your product.

Comment: look at the accepted answer -  it works.