# How to know update size on the Mac OS?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

The question I have is the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/755425/how-to-know-update-size-on-the-osx/755483#755483?newreg=21389ee9ea7349a08b6401600e97d8cf). However, I'm new here and I can't comment to ask more information about the provided answer...

The question is: How can you find out how big is the software update to be downloaded without starting the download? (I am using mobile data plan for internet on my Mac and need to know how much data the update will take).

There is one answer provided by @gurple:
`Running /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -l will display the size of the update in its listing of available updates. Take a peek at the man page for softwareupdate to learn about its features.`

I am guessing this means I need to open the Terminal and run the command `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -l` but doing this, seems to do nothing.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open a terminal and issue the command

```
softwareupdate -l
```

This will prompt the software-update mechanism in macOS to check and list all available updates for your current system.

I had to search for one mac to give me an available update as i tend to upgrade them. If there is no available upgrade you won't get a list of course.

Here's an example with an update:

```
% softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: macOS Big Sur 11.7.8-20G1351
    Title: macOS Big Sur 11.7.8, Version: 11.7.8, Size: 2700353K, Recommended: YES, Action: restart,
```

And this example has no updates available

```
% softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.
```

If you're interested in the size of full installers you can list them with

```
softwareupdate --list-full-installers
```

And here's an example listing as of today:

```
% softwareupdate --list-full-installers
Finding available software
Software Update found the following full installers:
* Title: macOS Ventura, Version: 13.4.1, Size: 11513284KiB, Build: 22F82, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Ventura, Version: 13.4, Size: 11511926KiB, Build: 22F66, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Ventura, Version: 13.3, Size: 11500012KiB, Build: 22E252, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Monterey, Version: 12.6.7, Size: 12115649KiB, Build: 21G651, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Monterey, Version: 12.6.6, Size: 12108302KiB, Build: 21G646, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Monterey, Version: 12.6.5, Size: 12115811KiB, Build: 21G531, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Monterey, Version: 12.6.4, Size: 12116269KiB, Build: 21G526, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.7.8, Size: 12120994KiB, Build: 20G1351, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.7.7, Size: 12121126KiB, Build: 20G1345, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.7.6, Size: 12120959KiB, Build: 20G1231, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.7.5, Size: 12120799KiB, Build: 20G1225, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.6.6, Size: 12121263KiB, Build: 20G624, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.6.5, Size: 12121404KiB, Build: 20G527, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.6.4, Size: 12147782KiB, Build: 20G417, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.6.3, Size: 12143674KiB, Build: 20G415, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.6.2, Size: 12141944KiB, Build: 20G314, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.6.1, Size: 12137180KiB, Build: 20G224, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Big Sur, Version: 11.5.2, Size: 12149332KiB, Build: 20G95, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Catalina, Version: 10.15.7, Size: 8055650KiB, Build: 19H15, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Catalina, Version: 10.15.7, Size: 8055522KiB, Build: 19H2, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Catalina, Version: 10.15.6, Size: 8055450KiB, Build: 19G2021, Deferred: NO
* Title: macOS Mojave, Version: 10.14.6, Size: 5896894KiB, Build: 18G103, Deferred: NO
```

I hope this answers your questions.